# Listening to LMS messages from a background utility bar item

Tags: utility-bar, lightning-message-service

I want to do some background processing so I wrote a background utility bar item, and tried listening to LMS messages, but it didn't work. Then I found this:

> It is a front-end service that works in client-side user interfaces, which would include **popped out utility bar item windows** and parent/child iFrame windows (primarily Visualforce).

So the window has to not only be visible, i.e. non-background, but also popped out? Why would they impose such a restriction? How can I get my background utility bar item to listen to LMS messages?

Comment: which version of LMS are you using? Are you using the Spring 20 beta, or the pre-release Summer 20 GA?

Comment: Spring '20. Actually I'm not exactly sure how to upgrade myself to Summer '20 pre-release, gotta figure that out.

Comment: If you just want to test if it works, easiest is probably to sign up for a pre-release Developer Edition org [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer20/). The sandbox preview window has passed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some features that have been added to LMS in the Summer 20 GA. The one that should help you is called *scope*.

There are two scopes, *active* (which is the default) and *application*.

Utility bar items are **always** treated as active (whether popped out, selected, or in the background).

There's information about this in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm) and there was a [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/06/learn-moar-lightning-message-service-generally-available-in-summer-20.html) published this past week to talk about the GA of LMS.

Comment: Hi there, I'm looking an answer on how to stream LMS messages/events without the need to have a click event. there is nothing mentioned in the DOCs. Unfortunately, that stops me from migrating from a VF in iFrame using a postMessage() to the simpler LMS channel messages. Works fine when sending the LMS message on click events. Trying to fake the clicks in the VF doesn't help. Link to my question is avialable here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/416378/128410