# What causes this WARN level message when using apex actionPoller and can we avoid it?

Tags: visualforce

I'm using an actionPoller to sync state between LWC & VF.

```
        <apex:actionPoller action="{!resend}" id="resend" interval="5" oncomplete="sendState(request,event,data)"/>
```

> WARNING: non-whitelisted event received (and ignored) on postmessage: markup://force__vfRecordDataInvalidation; data: undefined

The code that fires that is in a numbered source (like VM123456).

```
//
if(window.SfdcApp && window.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) {
    window.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.fireContainerEvent('force__vfRecordDataInvalidation', {}, true);
} else {
    console.log('[VFRecordDataInvalidation] Not in Lightning, not firing invalidation');
}
//
```

And the place where that is triggered is `windowMessageLibrary.AlohaIntegration.js`:

```
  function isWhitelistedEvent(event) {
    if(!event) {
      return false
    }
    if(event.indexOf("markup://") !== 0) {
      event = "markup://" + event
    }
    if(WHITELISTED_EVENTS.indexOf(event) > -1) {
      return true
    }
    $A.warning("non-whitelisted event received (and ignored) on postmessage: " + event + "; data: " + event.data);
    return false
  }
```

and the WHITELISTED_EVENTS does not hold it:

```
  var WHITELISTED_EVENTS = ["markup://one:back", "markup://force:navigateToURL", "markup://force:navigateToSObject", "markup://force:navigateToFeed", "markup://force:navigateToFeedItemDetail", "markup://force:navigateToRelatedList", "markup://force:navigateToList", "markup://force:navigateToObjectHome", "markup://force:navigateToState", "markup://force:createRecord", "markup://force:editRecord", "markup://force:setTitle", "markup://force:refreshView", "markup://native:notifyNative", "markup://force:toggleSpinner", 
  "markup://one:updateHeader", "markup://reports:runReportEvent", "markup://reports:queryDataProviderEvent", "markup://reports:closeReportBuilderEvent", "markup://opencti:clickToDial", "markup://force:navigateToComponent", "markup://desktopDashboards:setDashboardNameEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:queryDataProviderEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:toggleFeedPanelEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:setMaskEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:getItemsEvent", "markup://force:showToast", "markup://desktopDashboards:subscribeDashboardEvent", 
  "markup://desktopDashboards:dashboardChangeOwnerEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:invokeChatterPublisherEvent", "markup://desktopDashboards:downloadComponentImageEvent", "markup://force:userAssistanceMenuAlternativeUpdate", "markup://force:updateDraggableResizablePanelEvent", "markup://force:userAssistanceGlobalEvent", "markup://force:favoriteEvent", "markup://force:requestLogging", "markup://force:showAddressSuggestions", "markup://force:saveAddressLookup", "markup://setup:navigateToSetup", 
  "markup://onesetup:refreshTree", "markup://one:toggleNav", "markup://force:showActionsOverflow", "markup://force:reloadApplication", "markup://setup_service:socialLSFAuthDone", "markup://one:maskHeader", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eScrtEvent", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eConsoleLoad", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eConfigurationUpdated", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eConnectionError", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eFlagLowered", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eFlagRaised", 
  "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eLoginFailed", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eLoginSuccess", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eLogout", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eMenuStatusChanged", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eReconnecting", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eRequestComplete", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eStatusChanged", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eStatusChangeFailed", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkAccepted", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkAssigned", 
  "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkCancelled", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkloadChanged", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkClosed", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkDeclined", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eResyncStateSuccess", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:toolkitApiObject", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkTransferred", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkTransferError", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eCleanSlateLogin", 
  "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eAgentNotification", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorkReopenedOnLogin", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eWorksReopenedOnLogin", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eAfterConversationWorkStarted", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eEndAfterConversationWork", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eAfterConversationWorkEnded", "markup://runtime_service_omnichannel:eAcwExtensionProcessed", "markup://omni:eSCRTConnectionInfo", "markup://omni:scrtObject", 
  "markup://omni:eAgentsRefresh", "markup://omni:eAgentStatusChange", "markup://omni:eAgentLogout", "markup://omni:eAgentListUpdated", "markup://omni:eWorkQueueUpdated", "markup://omni:eWorkDetailListUpdated", "markup://omni:eAgentWorkUpdated", "markup://omni:eQueueItemsUpdated", "markup://omni:eSkillsItemsUpdated", "markup://omni:eWorksRefresh", "markup://omni:eWorkDetailRefresh", "markup://omni:eQueuesRefresh", "markup://omni:eConversationNewEntry", "markup://omni:eConversationSneakPeek", "markup://omni:eConversationFlagInfo", 
  "markup://omni:eSupervisorConfigChanged", "markup://omni:eSupervisorFlagLowered", "markup://omni:eMetricItemsUpdated", "markup://runtime_essential_checkout:checkoutCreditCardResponse", "markup://runtime_online_sales:verifyCreditCardResponse"];
  var API_BRIDGE_MESSAGE_TYPES = ["integrationApi/", "publisher."];
```

That error message is flooding the console in the case when the actionPoller is not disabled.

**Update:**

the Controller.cls

```
    public PageReference resend() {
        return null;
    }
```

in VF.page:

```
        <script type="module">
            import VFjavascriptModule from '{!URLFOR($Resource.vfPage, 'VFjavascriptModule.js')}';
            const lmsObj = {
                publish: sforce.one.publish,
                channelID: id:'{!$MessageChannel.State__c}',
            };

            const B = new VFjavascriptModule(lmsObj);
            window.sendState= function(){
                B.sendState(); // B is an instance of a class in Resource
            };
```

//the Resource VFjavascriptModule

```
export default class VFjavascriptModule {
    constructor(lms) {
        this.channelID = lms.channelID;
        this.publish = lms.publish;
        this._state = 'init';
        // for the illustration only:
        setTimeout(()=>{
                this._state = 'ready';
        }, 4*5000);

    }
    sendState() {
        const args = {value:this._state};
        this.publish(this.channelID, args); // sforce.one.publish
    }
}
```

// State channel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>State channel</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>state</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>State</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Comment: Without seeing the Apex code for resend and the JavaScript for sendState, we can't really help you. Please [edit] your question to include this code.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thank you for the note. I have updated the question with the requested code.

Comment: this specific question is related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/416378/128410 . It's different in the approach of where the main JS is placed. The difference in here is that main code is in a Module based inclusion of the static Resource. will update